# "Can not construct instance" on receipt of POST with JSON payload

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, post, spring-boot

I am working with Spring Boot and trying to accept a POST.

I'm getting an error message

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of biz.ianw.ukData.restServer.Controller$Car: 
no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor 
or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@24b515ad; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of biz.ianw.ukData.restServer.Controller$Car: 
no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor 
or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@24b515ad; line: 1, column: 2]
```

The code I'm testing is:

```
public class Car {
    private String color;       
    public Car() {}     
    public Car(String color) { this.color = color; }
    public String getColor() {  return color; }
    public void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String doSearch(@RequestBody Car data) {   
    logger.info("in search: {}", data); 
    return new String("Done.");     
}
```

and I'm sending the POST using jQuery:

```
    datablock.urlpath = "search";
    datablock.type = "POST";
    datablock.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    datablock.data = { color: "Blue" };

    $.ajax({
            type: datablock.type,
            url: server + datablock.urlpath,
            contentType: datablock.contentType,
            data: JSON.stringify(datablock.data)
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log("ajaxCall success: " + JSON.stringify(datablock) + " -> " + JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log("ajaxCall failure: " + JSON.stringify(datablock) + " -> " + response.message);
        });
```

The default constructor is present and the headers and body seem to be correct, showing the expected content type and payload:

[image]

and so I'm at a bit of a loss to interpret the error message.  Any suggestions what I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the target class, Car in this case, **cannot be a non-static inner class**.  It doesn't work embedded in the Controller class as in the problem.

The details are in [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html) but it boils down to the way Java added inner classes means they don't have the default constructor that Jackson requires.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was staring at my code and couldn't figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but a slight difference between mine and yours is, I never added a default constructor and after adding the same the app worked like a Gem.